# Alternatives to android.net.rtp.RtpStream for VoIP - deprecated starting from Android 12

Tags: android, voip, rtp

My Android app (Push-To-Talk) needs to manage Voip and up today I used android.net.rtp.RtpStream  library.

I need to:

- send, to a my server, a VoIP flow (using GSM codec, UDP packets), capturing audio from Android Smartphone microphone
- receive, from a my server, a VoIP flow (UDP packets, always by GSM codec), playing it in Android Smartphone loudspeaker.

It worked up to Android 11, but starting from Android 12 it doesn't work anymore because android.net.rtp.RtpStream  is deprecated.

In "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/RtpStream" no alternatives solution are mentioned, just deprecated.
I'm trying to understand if "android.telecom" library is the right solution.

I also saw some posts in StackOverFlow. I see there are some Android VoIp library in some old posts, but I'm wondering, before to select a way to solve this problem, if there is an official solution suggested from Google to use VoIP inside an Adroid app.

In addition, a part Google suggestion (if any), if you have experienced the same problem, suggestion about alternative libraries is welcome.